# View market depth/ orders on mtgox?

Tags: mtgox, market-depth

Excuse me if this is a stupid question, but does mtgox have an option to see market depth? The trading page allows me to set a price, but without know the current levels of bid/asks how can I make a judgement about what price to set?

Cryptoxchange seems to display this information on its trading page, but I can't seem to find it on mtgox.

Comment: Doesn't http://mtgoxlive.com/ show the market depth?

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to find it either, I'm pretty sure that they used to show it. The market depth is available [in their API](https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/fulldepth) though and if you want something a bit more user friendly it is also available on [Bitcoin Charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/mtgoxUSD_depth.html).

Answer (score 3):

for the reports you have:

mtgoxlive.com/orders

bitcoincharts.com/markets/mtgoxUSD_depth.html

for the source data you have:

en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v0#0.2FgetDepth.php (truncated)

en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Full_Depth (full)

Related thread on bitcointalk: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=194868.msg2023904#msg2023904

Answer (score 2):

Try http://classic.mtgox.com   --> trade data  --> market depth

you do not have to log in

Answer (score 1):

There is also [mtgoxlive.com/orders](http://mtgoxlive.com/orders), but they have had some trouble lately. I have also recently discovered http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/ which is nice, but lacks the nice display of order depth